# killing a process in java

Tags: java, kill-process

I have a little problem in killing a process. i can kill the process that can execute directly from run (eg: mspaint.exe, calc.exe) but i can't kill process which cannot execute from run (eg: wmplayer.exe)

here's what i did:

(what i can kill is)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {    

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM mspaint.exe ");

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

(and what i can't kill is)

```
try {

        //Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mspaint");

        String process = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Media Player\\wmplayer.exe";

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM process ");

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Comment: Your code is trying to kill a process named process.

Comment: the process contains the path of the actual process and i m unable to kill that how can i kill from that specific path ?

Comment: The point was the code as you've written it will never work because you never include the process name in the command you are running.

Comment: how to kill wmpalyer.exe then?  do u have some idea

Answer (score 1):

You are executing a command to kill a process named "process", literally. If you want to kill a process by name, you need to supply it the executable name and not the path.

```
String process = "wmplayer.exe";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM " + process);
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb491009.aspx

Comment: ya i can only kill the process which locates inside system32 but i am unable to kill process which is running from a different location. so how to kill the process of speicifc location?

Comment: Looking for the same thing, Killing process from particular path.

Answer (score -1):

do this

```
try {

        //Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mspaint");

        String process = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Media Player\\wmplayer.exe";

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM " +process );

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Comment: hi thanks, but this didnt worked out, i want to kill the process from specific loation